# Granting permission to application Paypal payment pro - unable to find apisignature - Beginner

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am integrating paypal payment pro (direct) to my website. According to [this project](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Samples/PayPalAPISample/Configuration.cs) i am looking for `APIUSERNAME`, `APIPASSWORD` AND `APISIGNATURE`.  But, i am unable to find the api signature as shown in the screenshot below.

The path i took is : PROFILE --> MY SELLING TOOLS --> API ACCESS (clicked on UPDATE)--> there is 2 options here (`Grant API permissions to a third party to use certain PayPal APIs on your behalf.`) or (`Option 2 - Request API credentials to create your own API username and password.`). I chose OPTION-2.

In Option 2 it only shows  `APIUSERNAME` and `APIPASSWORD`. `APISIGNATURE` is missing. I need to know how to get it. Help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both an API certificate and an API signature active on an account at the same time.  It appears you've created an API certificate in the past.

In order to request an API signature, remove the existing API certificate (note; be careful if this certificate is currently in use on any other sites, as it will cease working when you remove it from the account).

Once removed, you'll have the option to request an API signature.

Comment: Ok i removed the Certificate. Now, how can i request for `API Signature`. Can you give me step by step instructions? I have logged into my Developer account and now what should i do?